# Global variable is "null" when used in function

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, local-variables

thanks in advance.
I'm declaring my global variables at the beginning with const, but when I try to access it in the function, I get an error in my console saying it cannot declare property of 'null'.

Code below:

```
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('#thumbnail'); // album cover 
const song = document.querySelector('#song'); // audio object

const songArtist = document.querySelector('.song-artist'); // element where track artist appears
const songTitle = document.querySelector('.song-title'); // element where track title appears
const progressBar = document.querySelector('#progress-bar'); // element where progress bar appears
let pPause = document.querySelector('#play-pause'); // element where play and pause image appears
```

```
function playPause() {
    if (playing) {
        const song = document.querySelector('#song'),
        thumbnail = document.querySelector('#thumbnail');

      pPause.src = "./assets/icons/pause.png";
        thumbnail.style.transform = "scale(1.15)";

        song.play();
        playing = false;
    } else {

        pPause.src = "./assets/icons/play.png"
        thumbnail.style.transform = "scale(1)" 

        song.pause();
        playing = true;
    }
}
```

returns `Cannot set property 'src' of null`

And I get that error message at the first instance of `pPause`, where it doesn't recognize it even though I declared it at the beginning... ? It's doing this to all the globals with other functions as well.

The code works when I re-declare every global variable as a local variable in the needed function.

Comment: If `document.querySelector('#play-pause')` doesn't find any element it returns `null`. Make sure you wrap your code in [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: Do one of these `pPause.addEventListener('click', playPause)` or `window.playPause = function() {...}`, Hope it helps